# Subprocess not returning meaningful error messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, command-line-interface, stderr

What specific syntax must be changed in the Python code below in order for the python function to return the same correct error
message that the CLI command below is returning?

**THE CORRECT ERROR MESSAGE:**

The following CLI command returns a useful error message correctly as intended:

```
$ az repos import create --git-source-url https://github.com/SomeAccount/some-repo.git --repository SomeTargetRepo --git-service-endpoint-id  long-alpha-numeric-guid --organization https://dev.azure.com/SomeOrgName --project SomeProjectName --requires-authorization
Can only import into an empty repository.
```

**WRONG USELESS ERROR RESPONSE:**

But when the same CLI command gets run by the Python 3 function at bottom below, it
returns the following useless response which does not allow us to debug the cause of the error:

```
data string is: 
err is: None
process.returncode is: 1
Error: None
Error: Return Code is: 1
```

**CODE THAT RETURNS USELESS ERROR RESPONSE:**

The following Python 3 function is what is causing the useless error response to be returned:

```
def getShellJsonResponse(cmd,counter=0):
  process = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
  data = process.stdout
  err = process.stderr
  logString = "data string is: " + data
  print(logString)
  logString = "err is: " + str(err)
  print(logString)
  logString = "process.returncode is: " + str(process.returncode)
  print(logString)
  if process.returncode == 0:
    logString = str(data)
    print(logString)
    decodedData = data #.decode('utf-8')
    return decodedData
  else:
    logString = "Error: " + str(err)
    print(logString)
    logString = "Error: Return Code is: " + str(process.returncode)
    print(logString)
    sys.exit(1)
```

What specific syntax must be changed in the Python code above in order to return the meaningful error message which can be used to resolve the root cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you try something like this:

```py
# powershell command
getShellJsonResponse(['powershell', '-Command', 'Write-Host', '"Hello world"'])
# cmd command
getShellJsonResponse('echo "Hello world"')
```

You'll see that your routine is showing the standard out just fine. So, the problem must be with the command you are passing, or how you're passing it.

Since your code doesn't show how you're calling it, it's hard to say, but I did notice that I couldn't just run `az` directly. Something like this does produce the expected output though:

```
getShellJsonResponse([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd', 'account', 'list'])
```

Or, if you prefer passing a string:

```
getShellJsonResponse(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account list')
```

Note: do future you and everyone that has to work with you and your code a favour and start using a default indentation of 4 instead of 2 - this is Python, after all. If that means your code starts running off screen on the right, the problem is generally the structure of your code, not the indentation.